# How to specify in OpenAPI components/schemas, that named String property is not-nullable/required?

Tags: java, spring, openapi, springdoc

In my project, there is an **OpenAPI 3.0.1** spec. One of the schema components has property of type `array`.

```yaml
components:
  schemas:
    cardKey:
      description: ...
      format: base64
      type: string
    
    newRequest:
      description: ...
      properties:
        cardKeyList:
          description: ...
          items:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/cardKey'
          minItems: 1
          type: array
      required:
      - cards
```

The issue is, that in Java it translates to:

```java
@Valid
private List<String> cardKeyList = new ArrayList<>();
```

but I can't seem to find a way, to specify, that `cardKey`, that is present in that `ArrayList` can't be `null` as in `minLength`, must be at least 1.

As an additional info the project is written in *Java 17* and is based on *Spring Boot*. *OpenAPI* spec is used with *SpringDoc*.